# Нельзя использовать событие на клик из контекстного меню listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Возникает ошибка:

```
 InvalidCastException: Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem" к типу "System.Windows.Controls.Button".
```

```cs
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
        
namespace Wpcon
{ 
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<list_cams> list_camsl = new ObservableCollection<list_cams>();

        public class list_cams
        {
            public string Nomercam { get; set; }
            public string Adrescam { get; set; }
        }
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            list_camsl.Add(new list_cams { Nomercam ="12323", Adrescam = "asdasd" });
            list_cam.ItemsSource = list_camsl;
        }
        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ZZzzz");
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="list_cam" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="150px" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding cam_list}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="3">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Номер:" Foreground="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nomercam}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Адрес:" Foreground="DarkOrange" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Adrescam}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Редактировать"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Исправьте `Button button = (Button)sender;` на `MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;` в обработчике события `Samba`. Вы скопировали обработчик из какой-то кнопки и забыли поменять тип. Внимательнее надо быть.

Comment: @aepot немного не понял это где нужно выставить, я такого не нахожу. Да и ничего не копировал

Comment: private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: #line 52 "..\..\Window1.xaml"
            this.Add_cams.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.ClickEvent, new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.MenuItem_Click));

Comment: `<MenuItem Header="Удалить"  Click="Samba"/>` - а это что тогда такое? У вас есть метод, который называется `Samba`

Comment: я его переименовал на MenuItem_Click

Comment: Я в xaml не вижу, что вы его переименовали. Покажите актуальный код, отредактируйте вопрос. И зачем вам назначать одновременно обработчик и в xaml и в коде, выберите что-то одно. И да, покажите C# код, без него можно только гадать, что у вас за ошибка.

Comment: @aepot обновил вопрос

Comment: Вот теперь в показанном коде я не вижу причин для указанной ошибки. Ошибка за пределами показанного кода.

Comment: @aepot в том то и дело что это весь код.

Comment: А где ошибка возникает, в какой строке?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116911/discussion-between-tand-and-aepot).

Comment: @aepot в чате более подробно могу показать, дабы тут не писать лишние сообщения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там не все так просто с этим меню оказалось. Созданное внутри `ItemContainerStyle` оно оказалось не живое, ни для обработчиков событий, не для команд. Поэтому создал я его в ресурсах `ListBox`.

Я написал реализацию с командами. Для использования команд, вам нужно  добавить в проект класс, отдельным файлом. В проводнике решения выберите **Добавить - Класс - RelayCommand.cs**.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Вникать в его логику не обязательно на данном этапе. А использовать его достаточно просто.

Вот код окна

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Cam> _cams;
    private ICommand _editCommand;
    private ICommand _deleteCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<Cam> Cams
    {
        get => _cams;
        set
        {
            _cams = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); // эта штука позволяет сохранять связь с коллекцией если вы ее переприсвоите во время работы приложения
        }
    }

    public ICommand EditCommand => _editCommand ?? (_editCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Cam cam)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cam.Nomercam + " " + cam.Adrescam, "Редактировать");
        }
    }));

    public ICommand DeleteCommand => _deleteCommand ?? (_deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is Cam cam)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cam.Nomercam + " " + cam.Adrescam, "Удалить");
            Cams.Remove(cam);
        }
    }));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        // Не пишите в конструктор свой код, пишите его в обработчик Window.Loaded
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Cams = new ObservableCollection<Cam>();
        Cams.Add(new Cam { Nomercam = "12323", Adrescam = "asdasd" });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Класс данных отдельно

```cs
public class Cam : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _nomercam;
    private string _adrescam;

    public string Nomercam
    {
        get => _nomercam;
        set
        {
            _nomercam = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string Adrescam
    {
        get => _adrescam;
        set
        {
            _adrescam = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Разметка

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Width="1200" Height="600" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Cams}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="MyContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Редактировать" Command="{Binding DataContext.EditCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="3">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Номер:" Foreground="Black" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nomercam}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Адрес:" Foreground="DarkOrange" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Adrescam}" />
                        </DockPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Так же я немного переименовал ваши классы и переменные - [ссылка](https://habr.com/ru/post/26077/).