# Вызов команды в ContextMenu из DataContext Window

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, необходимо настроить выпадающее меню у ListBox. Нужно в нём вызывать команды из DataContext окна. Пробую сделать это вот так вот :

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
     <ListBox.ContextMenu>
         <ContextMenu>
             <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
         </ContextMenu>
     </ListBox.ContextMenu>
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
             <Border Background="{Binding BackGroundColor, Converter={StaticResource ColorToBrushConverter}}" Padding="5 0" MinWidth="100">
                 <StackPanel>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                     <Button Content="TEST" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                 </StackPanel>                                                            
                 </Border>                                                        
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

При этом у объекта Button тот же самый Binding нормально срабатывает. А у MenuItem команда почему-то не вызывается. Что я делаю не так и как достучаться до DataContext window из ContextMenu?

Не уверен влияет или нет, всё происходит внутри TreeView/DataTemplate и у ContextMenu текущий DataContext похоже берётся от DataTemplate

```
 <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Ports}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
   ...
     <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Device}">
```

Comment: У контекстного меню есть свойство `PlacementTarget`, через него можно выйти на дерево.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, PlacementTarget помог для передачи параметра в команду. А вот к самой команде зашёл с другой стороны. Создал в StaticResource окна объект ViewModel и назначил его в качестве DataContext. Дальше уже вызывал так :  _<MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteCategoryCommand, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelProvider}}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
          />_

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213584/373567

Answer (score 0):

Контекстное меню не является частью визуального дерева окна, и поэтому не имеет `Window` в качестве своего предка. Следовательно, относительный источник в `RelativeSource` не находится и получаем ошибку привязки.
При этом контекстное меню наследует `DataContex` элемента в котором было вызвано (`ListBox`), который, в свою очередь, наследует `DataContex` окна. Поэтому в этом случае достаточно

```
<MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteCategoryCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Это было то, что я попробовал в первую очередь `Command="{Binding DeleteCategoryCommand}"`, не сработало, т.к. у меню DataContext не тот в котором находится команда. У меня большая цепочка вложенностей получается из-за того, что всё это находится внутри динамически наполняемого TreeView. Как-то возможно всё же с любого элемента напрямую обратиться к window? Ну или есть что-то по типу `App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext`

Answer (score 0):

Остановился на следующем решении:

Объявил `DataContext` не на стороне кода, а в `XAML`. Но в моём случае это осложнилось тем, что мой `ViewModel` не имеет конструкторов без параметров, и в качестве параметра принимает вызывающее его окно.

Поэтому пришлось создать, видимо, реализацию паттерна "Фабричный метод"?

```
public static MainWindowViewModel CreateWithWindow(Window window)
{
    return new MainWindowViewModel(window);
}
```

Дальше на стороне `XAML` создаём объект:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MainWindowViewModelProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type cmd:MainWindowViewModel}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <Window>{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}</Window>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
```

и назначаем его в качестве `DataContext` окна:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource MainWindowViewModelProvider}" />
</Window.DataContext>
```

И теперь из контекстного меню можно будет вызвать эту команду через статический объект. Так же есть некоторые заморочки с тем, чтобы передать в качестве параметра выбранный объект:

```
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>                                                     
        <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteCategoryCommand, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelProvider}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
        />
    </ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

И похоже вот здесь я что-то делаю не правильно:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MainWindowViewModelProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type cmd:MainWindowViewModel}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
                <Window>{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}</Window>
            </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

хотя, возможно, отсюда это нельзя сделать в принципе? В общем в конструктор, похоже, просто передался объект `new Window`, а не наше окно.

Также пробовал передать вот так:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MainWindowViewModelProvider" ObjectType="{x:Type cmd:MainWindowViewModel}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Но здесь уже, видимо, проблеме с тем, что инициализация происходит в каком-то неврном порядке. В общем, сбой на этапе

```
InitializeComponent();
```

Похоже, от идеи передавать само окно в качестве параметра в конструктор `ViewModel` придётся отказаться.

Применил обходное решение с добавлением параметра уже после инициализации:

```
public MainWindow()
{           
    InitializeComponent();
    (DataContext as MainWindowViewModel).MainWindow = this;
}
```

В целом сейчас вроде бы всё работает так, как я хотел. Но в плане правильности применённых решений вот вообще не уверен.

Comment: Это нарушение MVVM и так делать нельзя. При этом суть ответа слабо связана с вопросом.

Comment: Вопрос я и задавал. Этот код решает поставленную задачу. Вероятно он делает это не так. Скорее всего нарушает паттерны. Буду счастлив если подскажете, как сделать менее топорно. По MVVM есть какой-то общепринятый стандарт? Просто постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что на многие вопросы говорят, что это нарушает MVVM, но как сделать без нарушения хз.

Comment: @aepot скорее всего есть какое-то простое решение с правильным биндингом. А не этот велосипед со статическим ресурсом. Но нагуглить его не получилось. Так же об это убились все нейронки до которых я смог дотянуться, включая GPT 4. В общей сумме уже около 10 часов на это убил. И то что выше, единственный вариант который сработал.

Comment: Кажется вопрос только касался того, как забиндить команду в контекстном меню из вьюмодели окна. А ответ совсем про другое. При этом вопроса о том как окна закрывать и т.д. не стояло. Также вы ниразу не упомянули, а что же должна делать кнопка. В итоге получается смесь двух или более проблем. Вопрос про одну, ответ про другую. Отредактируйте ответ, уберите лишнее, оставьте только то, что непосредственно отвечает на изначальный вопрос. Если появился новый вопрос - можно задать его отдельно.

Comment: @aepot убрал строку про закрытие окна. По коду, боюсь тут всё друг за друга цепляется и одно без другого работать не будет.  Сам ответ по сути вот : `<MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteCategoryCommand, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModelProvider}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
        />` - но как задать ViewModel в качестве статического ресурса окна, задача не самая тривиальная на мой неопытный взгляд.

Comment: По поводу того что должна делать кнопка - вызывать метод и передавать в него параметр. Метод должен удалять из коллекции выделенный объект.

Comment: Вот вы обращаетесь к `PlacementTarget.SelectedItem` что мешает обращаться к `PlacementTarget.DataContext`? Зачем статик ресурс вообще? Точно не лишнее?

Comment: @aepot вероятно мешает то, что я не понимаю, как прописать Binding о котором вы говорите. Пробовал так `Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.DeleteCategoryCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"` не работает. Пробовал вот так `Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.DeleteCategoryCommand}"` тоже не работает. Так же пробовал выкинув из строки DataContext
Команда через PlacementTarget отказывается работать. Но передача параметра вполне себе работает

Comment: CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" - прекрасно передаётся. Видимо корень проблемы в том, что PlacementTarget приводит в DataContext не окна, а элемента в который вложено меню.